# Notepad++: How to remove a section of text with regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a file that has lines like:

```
string1,string2,string3
```

I would like it to just be

```
string2
```

How would I use regular expression to do this?

Comment: Meaning, you want just column 2 in a CSV file, or is it specifically targeting `string1,` and `,string3`?

Comment: I just want column 2 in a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have strictly 3 columns, and strings do not contain comas ( `,` ) and are separated by comas ( `,` ), then:

find:

> `(.+),(.+),(.+)`

replace

> `\2`